# MVC3 Base Contoller Crashes, Same Code Works in Inherited Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, inheritance, singleton

## Background

.NET 4, C#, MVC3, using [JsonFx](http://jsonfx.net/) to serialize and deserialize data.  Base controller has been extended to intercept all requests and do the following:

1. Get some JSON from a remote server.
2. Run a LINQ query based on passed in keys (hero, body, footer).
3. Return a generic model to the view.

This code works fine when running in a controller inheriting from the base controller, but when placed in the Base controller and called from an inherited controller, I get the following error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression'.
```

This is the offending line:

```
    var queryHero = heroModel.ArrayItems().Where(o => o.DisplayName == keyHero);
```

## Question

How do I avoid getting a type error when in the base controller?  It's the same code that runs fine in the inherited controller.

Thanks for your time.

## Full Code

```
public models.GenericPageModel GetGenericPageContent(string keyHero, string keyBody, string keyFooter)
{
    try
    {
        // get content "tables"
        var heroContent = GetJson("Page_Section_Hero_Content");
        var bodyContent = GetJson("Page_Section_Body_Content");
        var footerContent = GetJson("Page_Section_Footer_Content");

        // new reader
        var reader = new JsonReader(new DataReaderSettings(new DataContractResolverStrategy()));

        // read it
        var heroModel = reader.Query<models.PageSectionHeroContent>(heroContent);
        var bodyModel = reader.Query<models.PageSectionBodyContent>(bodyContent);
        var footerModel = reader.Query<models.PageSectionFooterContent>(footerContent);

        // run query for current page
        var queryHero = heroModel.ArrayItems().Where(o => o.DisplayName == keyHero);
        var queryBody = bodyModel.ArrayItems().Where(o => o.DisplayName == keyBody);
        var queryFooter = footerModel.ArrayItems().Where(o => o.DisplayName == keyFooter);

        // models for return
        models.PageSectionHeroContent hero;
        models.PageSectionBodyContent body;
        models.PageSectionFooterContent footer;

        // any hero content?
        if (queryHero.Any())
            hero = new models.PageSectionHeroContent { DisplayName = queryHero.FirstOrDefault().DisplayName, 
                ContentXML = queryHero.FirstOrDefault().ContentXML };
        else
            hero = new models.PageSectionHeroContent { DisplayName = "Sorry, there was an error.", 
                ContentXML = "<details><error>No data was returned.</error></details>" };

        // any body content?
        if(queryBody.Any())
            body = new models.PageSectionBodyContent { DisplayName = queryBody.FirstOrDefault().DisplayName, 
                ContentXML = queryBody.FirstOrDefault().ContentXML };
        else
            body = new models.PageSectionBodyContent { DisplayName = "Sorry, there was an error.", 
                ContentXML = "<details><error>No data was returned.</error></details>" };

        // any footer content?
        if(queryFooter.Any())
            footer = new models.PageSectionFooterContent { DisplayName = queryFooter.FirstOrDefault().DisplayName, 
                ContentXML = queryFooter.FirstOrDefault().ContentXML };
        else
            footer = new models.PageSectionFooterContent { DisplayName = "Sorry, there was an error.", 
                ContentXML = "<details><error>No data was returned.</error></details>" };

        // build generic page model
        var model = new models.GenericPageModel { PageSectionHeroContent = hero, PageSectionBodyContent = body, PageSectionFooterContent = footer };

        return model;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {   
        //todo: handle, log exception
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because of context, have you considered the order of initialization of classes?

Comment: Jani, can you elaborate? To which classes are you referring and what order would you recommend?

Comment: BaseController and Inherited one I mean, First the parent will be created and I guess you may access a property that will be initialized by inherited class (maybe).

Comment: @Jani--So, are you saying that we (I am on the same dev team) should move this method out of the base controller into a separate class that is initialized later than the base?  That sounds like its worth a try.

Comment: Hmmmmm. Aren't BaseController and inherited instantiated by MVC? I am new to MVC, btw, so I may not understand fully. How would I control their creation? Also, can you take a look at this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148788/ninject-not-binding-object-in-basecontroller-in-mvc3. It seems possible that JsonFx is suffering from the same condition. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Update: This problem is not specific to the BaseController. I've moved this function into a separate class file and it still barfs. And crazy enough the same thing happens if I move the function into an inherited controller. It is, as the error suggests, a LINQ issue, nothing to do with MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't be sure what it is that is NOT initializing on time in the `BaseController`, but found a work-around.

**DISCLAIMER:**  I am on the same dev team as `boynamedjib` and this solution may be suited the best for our particular situation.  Having said that, the solution is worth posting, we feel, as it might help others who encounter this quirk.

## Solution

The solution was found in making use of a combination of `dynamic` types and `ExpandoObjects` that are specific to C# 4.0, as well as the `IDictionary` type.

```
 public models.GenericPageDataModel GetGenericPageContent(string keyHero, string keyBody, string keyFooter)
        {
            try
            {
                var pageData = new List<models.GenericPageData>
                             {
                                 new models.GenericPageData{Key = "HeroModel",Value = GetJson("pro_Page_Section_Hero_Content")},
                                 new models.GenericPageData{Key = "BodyModel",Value = GetJson("pro_Page_Section_Body_Content")},
                                 new models.GenericPageData{Key = "FooterModel",Value = GetJson("pro_Page_Section_Footer_Content")}
                             };

                var reader = new JsonReader();

                var model = new models.GenericPageDataModel();
                foreach (var p in pageData)
                {
                    var objList = new List<ExpandoObject>();
                    dynamic output = reader.Read(p.Value);
                    foreach (var h in output)
                    {
                        dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
                        foreach (dynamic o in h)
                        {
                            var item = obj as IDictionary<String, object>;
                            item[o.Key] = o.Value;
                        }
                        objList.Add(obj);
                    }
                    switch (p.Key)
                    {
                        case ("HeroModel"):
                            model.HeroModel = objList.FirstOrDefault(o => o.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Key.Equals("DisplayName")).Value.Equals(keyHero));
                            break;
                        case ("BodyModel"):
                            model.BodyModel = objList.FirstOrDefault(o => o.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Key.Equals("DisplayName")).Value.Equals(keyBody));;
                            break;
                        case ("FooterModel"):
                            model.FooterModel = objList.FirstOrDefault(o => o.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Key.Equals("DisplayName")).Value.Equals(keyFooter));;
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
                return model;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

## Supporting Models

```
public class GenericPageData
        {
            public string Key { get; set; }
            public string Value { get; set; }
        }

        public class GenericPageDataModel
        {
            public ExpandoObject HeroModel { get; set; }
            public ExpandoObject BodyModel { get; set; }
            public ExpandoObject FooterModel { get; set; }
        }
```

## Razor Usage

```
@model my.project.com.Models.ContentModels.GenericPageDataModel        

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My Title";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

    ViewBag.heroDisplayName = @Model.HeroModel.ToDictionary(p => p.Key).FirstOrDefault(k => k.Key.Equals("DisplayName")).Value.Value;
}

<h1> @ViewBag.heroDisplayName</h1>
```